# How to make pagination's circle of slider using CSS only?

Tags: css

I'm using a Slider where I need to make pagination like this:

[image]

I will use a CSS sprite image for this but I'm just curious to know if it's possible to make with CSS3 and without using an image

the HTML which I want to use for this includes:

```
<ol id="pagination">
<li><a href="#slide1" class="active">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#slide2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#slide3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#slide4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#slide5">5</a></li>
</ol>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danVW/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9YTwk/1/

I think, this is what you're looking for. Of course, the CSS has to be modified a bit to get the gradient / shadow.

// edited, to make it more look-a-like: http://jsfiddle.net/9YTwk/4/

Comment: +1 cool it can be used on transparent background too http://jsfiddle.net/9YTwk/3/

Comment: Added a new version which looks more like your image.

Comment: For completeness, added a little switcher to @JitendraVyas's version http://jsfiddle.net/nathan/9YTwk/7/

Comment: *@Sn0opy's version, not Jitendra's.